# Error while running script in elastic search , gateway timeout

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, timeout, api-gateway, http-status-code-504

while running script in elastic search, I got 504 Gateway timeout error.

```
 {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "script": {
              "script": " doc['creted_date'].date.getMonthOfYear() == 12 "
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "test": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "creted_date",
            "interval": "month",
            "format": "MMM"

          },
          "aggs": {
            "cost": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "cost"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Error result :

```
 {
      "statusCode": 504,
      "error": "Gateway Time-out",
      "message": "Client request timeout"
    }
```

whenever I am running this script over index having small number of documents , it gives perfect output. but on index having large number of documents , it gives above error.

Can we manually set the timeout for request in elastic search ? or Is there any other solution for this problem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this for Elasticsearch 6.x.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source":  "doc['created_on'].date.getMonthOfYear() == params.month",
              "params": {
                "month": 5
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not asking for the query. My query is perfectly working for the index having small no of documents. But the problem is timeout. Is there any configuration we need to do in elastic search ?

Comment: It's not what kavi was asking about.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "expression",
          "script": "doc['creted_date'].getMonth() == month-1",
          "params": {
            "month": 12
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: not working ."type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[script] query does not support [lang]"

Comment: which Elasticsearch version you are using ?

Comment: I am using elastic search 6.0

Comment: Ok. try my below answer for elasticsearch 6.x.

Comment: Thanks for reply.But there is no mistake in my query. Its perfect. The problem is the timeout for the query request in elastic search. Can we change the timeout ? Yes. then How ?